# Add multiple elements to List

Tags: c#, recursion, syntax-error

for background: I have the following code to recursively search for files through a directory, which returns a list of all documents. I want to have the foldername and the documentname.
So far so good. It works well as long as I want to write two elements to my List.

I have a class Companyentry;

```
class Companyentry
    {
        public string Entry { get; set; }
        public string Folder { get; set; }

        public Companyentry(string ey, string fd)
        {
            Entry = ey;
            Folder = fd;
        }
    }
```

And my code to write to the List:

```
List<string> companylist = new List<string>();

private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // ListView initialisierem
            listView1.Columns.Add("Dateiname", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Unternehmen", 20, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
            listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(rootfolder);
            Console.WriteLine("No search pattern returns:");


            //Write to List
            foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {

                // Entries
                string[] Split = (fi.Directory.Name).Split(new Char[] { '_' });
                strEntry = (Split[1]);

                companylist.Add(new Companyentry("Entry", "Folder"));

            }
```

I got the following error that "Argument 1 cannot convert from Companyentry to 'string' ":

[Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMTgQ.png)

Whats wrong?

Comment: `companylist` is list of string, how do you want to add `Companyentry` instance to that list? Maybe make sense to call `ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Because this line is wrong:

```
companylist.Add(new Companyentry("Entry", "Folder"));
```

Change to this:

```
companylist.Add("Entry", "Folder");
new Companyentry("Entry", "Folder");
```

List is a string list.